# ASP.net MVC Keeping Session Alive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find a way to keep my session alive when Controller is taking long time to come back with results. My Javascript on button click looks like below:

```
function OnClick(s, e) {
        positionDate = ReportingPositionDate.GetDate().toDateString();

        if (true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: "@Url.Action("DataFileUpload", "ImportData")",
                data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
                dataType: "text",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
                success: function (msg) {
                    debugger;
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                    ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
                    ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
                    lpImport.Hide();
                },
                Error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

basically session times out before I get Success. I would like to silently keep session alive. 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web for same. There were responses but they were incorrect.
I was eventually able to tweak  one of them,  and this is the result:

-- Create an asp.net mvc app;
add the following to the home controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult KeepSessionAlive()
    {

        return new JsonResult { Data = "Postback " + on " + DateTime.Now};
    }
```

----Add the following to index.cshtml:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
 @section scripts{
<script src="~/SessionUpdater.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SessionUpdater.Setup('@Url.Action("KeepSessionAlive","Home")');
</script>
```

}
-- reference the following js file [in addition to referencing jquery]

```
SessionUpdater = (function () {
var clientMovedSinceLastTimeout = false;
var keepSessionAliveUrl = null;
//var timeout = 5 * 1000 * 60; // 5 minutes
var timeout = 15000; // 15 seconds for testing

function setupSessionUpdater(actionUrl) {
    // store local value
    keepSessionAliveUrl = actionUrl;
//    alert(actionUrl);
    // setup handlers
    listenForChanges();
    // start timeout - it'll run after n minutes
    checkToKeepSessionAlive();
}

function listenForChanges() {
    $("body").on("mousemove keydown", function () {
        clientMovedSinceLastTimeout = true;
    });
}


// fires every n minutes - if there's been movement ping server and restart timer
function checkToKeepSessionAlive() {
    setTimeout(function () { keepSessionAlive(); }, timeout);
}

function keepSessionAlive() {
    // if we've had any movement since last run, ping the server


   if (!clientMovedSinceLastTimeout && keepSessionAliveUrl != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: keepSessionAliveUrl,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#span').text(data);
                $('#myDiv').append('<br/>' + data);
                // reset movement flag
                clientMovedSinceLastTimeout = false;
                // start listening for changes again
                listenForChanges();
                // restart timeout to check again in n minutes
                 checkToKeepSessionAlive();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR");
                console.log("Error posting to " & keepSessionAliveUrl);
            }
        });
   }
   else {
       clientMovedSinceLastTimeout = false;
       listenForChanges();
       checkToKeepSessionAlive();
   }

}

// export setup method
return {
    Setup: setupSessionUpdater
};

 })();
```

Comment: The only thing wrong I see in this idea is that if you move all the time but never request anything from the server, your server will timeout the session anyway.  Am I wrong ?

Comment: Here's a corrected version of your HttpPost 

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult KeepSessionAlive()
        {

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = "Postback on " + DateTime.Now.ToString() 
            };
        }